# creating project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to create a project in eclipse in which the following directory gets generated automatically.

```
src/
tests/
projects.xml
meta-src/
```

So under which category this project will be falling. I was creating maven project. But it will be having lot more directories. So is there any specific project under which this will be falling? Or I can simply do Java project and keep on adding necessay files and directories?

Comment: Not quite sure about what you asking, are you going to use maven along with your java project or not?

Comment: no I won't be using maven project.

Answer (score 1):

Java project should be fine, you can set up auto-save actions etc no matter what the project type I believe.